# get id based on join two dataframes of two columns

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

HI guys i have two dataframe

```
val pos_articles_Gold = spark.load("jdbc", Map("url" -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:System/maher@//localhost:1521/XE", "dbtable" -> "IPTECH.TMP_PRIXVENTEPERM")).select("SITE", "REFART", "PRIXV", "CTVA").limit(20)
val pos_articles = spark.load("jdbc", Map("url" -> url, "dbtable" -> "pos_articles")).select("id","article_id","pos_id")

pos_articles_Gold.printSchema()
pos_articles.printSchema()

root
 |-- SITE: decimal(5,0) (nullable = false)
 |-- REFART: string (nullable = false)
 |-- PRIXV: decimal(13,3) (nullable = false)
 |-- CTVA: decimal(5,2) (nullable = false)

root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- article_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- pos_id: long (nullable = false)
```

**pos_article**

```
id,article_id,pos_id
17,434004740,96
18,395090520,12
19,395090520,1
20,395090520,10
21,395090520,7
24,20100160,2
```

**pos_articles_gold**

```
SITE,REFART,PRIXV,CTVA
96,434004740,1.250,18.00
12,395090520,999.000,18.00
1,395090520,999.000,18.00
10,395090520,999.000,18.00
7,395090520,999.000,18.00
```

the result should be

```
id,article_id,pos_id
24,20100160,2
```

What I would like to do is to

select id from  pos_articles  where article_id !=REFART and the pos_id!=SITE 
here what i tried so far , to avoid make a select and then an except

```
val exluded_Id = pos_articles.join(pos_articles_Gold, $"article_id" === $"REFART" && $"pos_id" === $"SITE","left")
val deletedrows=pos_articles.select("id").except(exluded_Id)
```

I guess I need to join the pos_articles_Gold dataframe and the pos_articles dataframe, any help will be appreciated

Comment: I guess when you have an answer to this question, you will delete this post and use the answer in your other question. won't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is create temp view on dataframes and run a sql query to fetch the required result, something like below:

```
import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._

val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test")
sparkConf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true")

val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()

pos_articles_Gold.createOrReplaceTempView("pos_articles_Gold")
pos_articles.createOrReplaceTempView("pos_articles")

val dataFrame = sparkSession.sql("SELECT * FROM pos_articles WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM pos_articles, pos_articles_Gold WHERE article_id =REFART AND pos_id=SITE)")
dataFrame.show
```

**output:**

```
+---+----------+------+
| id|article_id|pos_id|
+---+----------+------+
| 24|  20100160|     2|
+---+----------+------+
```

Comment: i got the following error when using your solution  Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Both sides of this join are outside the broadcasting threshold and computing it could be prohibitively expensive. To explicitly enable it, please set spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled = true; Thanks

Comment: @MaherHTB you need to add `spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled` to your `SparkConf`, I have updated my answer accordingly....

Answer (score 0):

You method is working but instead of `left` `join` use `inner join` as

```
val exluded_Id = pos_articles.join(pos_articles_Gold, pos_articles("article_id") === pos_articles_Gold("REFART") && pos_articles("pos_id") === pos_articles_Gold("SITE"))
  .select("id", "article_id", "pos_id")
pos_articles.except(exluded_Id).show(false)
```

Another way is

```
pos_articles.except(
  pos_articles.join(pos_articles_Gold, pos_articles("article_id") === pos_articles_Gold("REFART") && pos_articles("pos_id") === pos_articles_Gold("SITE"))
  .select("id", "article_id", "pos_id")
)
```

You should get your desired result